# Hyperlink with query string and open in new window in asp.net Datagrid

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

First of all, I have searched probably all threads on Stack OverFlow about my problem. Since I haven't find any expected result, so I forced my self to post this question.

### My problem is: I am using hyperlink in datagrid and passing datafield as querystring, I want pop-up window to be open with querystring in URL, when click on following link.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkViewDoc" Text='View Document' NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("javascript:window.open('ViewDoc.aspx?DocP={0}', 'MsgWindow','width=200,height=100')", Eval("vchDocPath")) %>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

### On above code, I am getting error "The server tag is not well performed.". Can anyone please provide me exact code?

---

I tried another format. In following code, I am not getting error, but when clicking on link, nothing is happening like link is not clickable.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkViewDoc" Text='View Document' NavigateUrl='Javascript:void(window.open("<%# Eval("vchDocPath", "ViewDoc.aspx?DocP={0}") %>","mywindow","toolbar=0,width=500,height=500"))' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

---

P.S: I have tried many other formats from stack overflow and other sites, but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: u sure it needs to be a hyperlink? why don't you do this on a <button and onclick, call a javascript with a passed value; something like ShowWindow( Eval("vchDocPath"));

Comment: I was looking for this alternate also, can you please add line of code, how to call function on OnClick in hyperlink with datafield in parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a sample html button that passes parameter to a javascript function..

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField>
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <button onclick='<%# "ShowWindow(\"" + "ViewDoc.aspx?DocP=" + Eval("vchDocPath") + "\")" %>'>View Document</button>
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>    

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowWindow(e) {
        window.open(e, "mywindow", "toolbar=0,width=500,height=500");
    }

</script>
```